# xampp and network

Tags: codeigniter, networking, xampp

I have build a site working on my localhost using xampp on windows7.
Now, I my colleagues want to access and use that site in our small office.

I tried to access the site using IP address of my own system. but some urls are redirecting to  localhost... and there is no localhost at other computers in my office.

the problem is the site is built with CodeIgniter framework so it containes a constant `site_url` which it's value is `http://localhost/site`.

I know that I need a server (or domain controller) and I have to put my site on that server so all other computers would access to it.

I can't figure out how to implement what is need without a computer used as server in our office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use the IP address or the hostname. To get the hostname just run:

```
hostname
```

in the command prompt. The IP Address is usually something like `192.168.1.121`

The only thing left is that on "xxamp" you need to make sure other people other than localhost  have access. Although I'm pretty sure your using WAMP if your hosting on windows 7...

So the site_url would be `http://192.168.1.121/site` or `http://my_hostname/site`

Comment: No it is XAMPP, but your solution should work. I'll try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Try  to change that var from localhost/s ite to 192.168.xxx.xxx/site  (your comp local Ip)

If u have a router configure it to forward port 80. Most of routers have an option to set Virtual Server

Comment: IF its for the local office he doesn't need to go near the router, in fact it means he's opening the site to the public without any need to.

Comment: Right, sry :) forward to be visible online